# where do "prohibit" routes come from and how to remove them

Tags: linux, routing, route

I have an entry in my routing table on my Linux router that I didn't add:

```
prohibit 2604:[redacted]:d772 from :: dev lo  proto kernel  src 2607:[redacted]::1  metric 4294967295  error -13 pref medium
```

and I can't seem to remove:

```
# ip -6 route del prohibit 2604:[redacted]:d772
RTNETLINK answers: No such process
# ip -6 route del prohibit 2604:[redacted]:d772 from :: dev lo  proto kernel  src 2607:[redacted]::1
RTNETLINK answers: No such process
```

So as much as I want to remove that "prohibit" route (feed a man a fish), I'd also like to know how it got added (teach a man to fish) since I know I didn't add it and it's not part of my configuration.